# Updating input affects other input yet there is no binding

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-directives

Here is my HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of formData; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <td *ngFor="let rowdata of formData[i]; let j = index" [attr.data-index]="j">
        <input type="checkbox" name="row-{{i}}-{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="formData[i][j]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see I've set unique names on the `checkboxes` to isolate them completely.

`formData` follows a structure like this:

```
formData = [
            [false, false],
            [true, true],
            [false, true]
          ]
```

The form populates correctly.

Checkboxes are generated correctly, however, there is some odd behavior :

When I click the checkbox for the first column, it also checks the box for second column ; this seems like total random behavior, but when I check a box for the second column, it has no affect on the checkbox for the first column

Any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT**

**Observation**: I changed the `input` to a standard input (not checkbox).

I changed the form values to "true", "false".. instead of true, false.

When I try to change the text in the input, I can only type one character and the input box "deselects" (i.e- I have to keep clicking on the input box to activate it every time I type a character)

**EDIT**

HTML Output as requested:

[image]

Comment: did you add group name?

Comment: Can you explain what this is?

Comment: Oh, the inputs are not inside a `form` tag, do they need to be?

Comment: I dont know what is going on there, but maybe you could create angular formgroup out of your data

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this as the table is dynamically populated from server data and is a lot easier with a template-driven solution. I'm also curious as to why the above code causes problems

Comment: I have simplified the problem.. might be easier to find the error now.

Comment: @DennisCallanan could you possibly give us the output html? Or a working version/example of this

Comment: @Deckerz I have no working version of this. I've simplified the code to the bare minimum to help locate the problem. Do you want me to inspect the element and copy the output HTML from there?

Comment: @DennisCallanan please if you could

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Comment: Something weird is happening. I created plunkr to test this. There is a template variable for form which is passed to formChange method when the form detects a change and it console.logs the value of it. You can see that properties are getting removed from the if for some reason when checking/unchecking https://plnkr.co/edit/5gicfdcUjdQCnWRf0SaF?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using trackBy in the second ngFor made it work for me :

**Template :**

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of formData['rows']; let i = index;" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <td *ngFor="let rowdata of formData['rows'][i]; let j = index; trackBy: trackByIndex" [attr.data-index]="j">
      <input type="checkbox" id="row-{{i}}-{{j}}" name="row-{{i}}-{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="formData['rows'][i][j]"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Component :**

Define the trackByIndex function :

```
trackByIndex(index: number, value: number) {
  return index;
}
```

The reason to use a trackBy is explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423#issuecomment-236808128) (credit goes to [zoechi@github](https://github.com/zoechi)) :

> you're iterating the items you're editing and they are primitive
>   values. ngFor can't keep track by identity because when the value
>   changes from 1 to 3 (by editing) it becomes a different identity.
>   Either use a custom trackBy that tracks by index or use objects
>   instead of primitive values.